# Why this media query not toggling the display property?

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
      body {
      color: white;
      background-color: #1E1B1B;
      border-color: grey;
      }
      .navbar {
      height: 50px;
      border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
      button.nav-btn, button.drop-down-toggle {
      float:right;
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 1px solid grey;
      color: white;
      padding: 5px 12px;
      font-size: 30px;
      cursor: pointer;
      }

      @media (max-width: 500px) {
      button.drop-down-toggle {
          display: none;
          border: 1px solid red;
      }
      }
    </style>

    <script>

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="navbar">
      <button class="drop-down-toggle" style="float:left; display:block;"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
      <button class="nav-btn"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i></button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you run the code and lower screen size to below 500px, then the border becomes red as expected, but it should be actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline styles have the highest priority of all CSS and your button does have

```
style= "display: block"
```

I would suggest to avoid inline css, another alternative is using `!important` at the media query

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
      button.drop-down-toggle {
      display: none !important;
      border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
      body {
      color: white;
      background-color: #1E1B1B;
      border-color: grey;
      }
      .navbar {
      height: 50px;
      border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
      button.nav-btn, button.drop-down-toggle {
      float:right;
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 1px solid grey;
      color: white;
      padding: 5px 12px;
      font-size: 30px;
      cursor: pointer;
      }

      @media (max-width: 500px) {
      button.drop-down-toggle {
          display: none;
          border: 1px solid red;
      }
      }
    </style>

    <script>

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="navbar">
      <button class="drop-down-toggle" style="float:left;"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
      <button class="nav-btn"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i></button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```